# AMP for WP шаблоны страниц

Tags: wordpress, amp

Может кто-то уже сталкивался.
Поставил плагин AMP for WP, но не нашел как в теме переопределять и создавать новые шаблоны. Сейчас он выводит пустые страницы, но если конструктором создать контент, то он будете выводиться, а меня не интересует конструктор, мне нужно циклом выводить посты. А архивные страницы CPT выдают 404, как создать шаблон archive-portfolio.php

Смотрел вот эту [документацию](https://ampforwp.com/tutorials/article/create-custom-template-post-type-taxonomy-amp-theme-framework/), поставил AMP Theme Framework, но там как-то не четко описано что да как.

Сам AMP Theme Framework ставится как плагин и потом там же его нужно редактировать (как показано на видео этой документации), а меня интересует как в своей теме переопределять шаблоны страниц, как это работает с woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

В общем плагин AMP for WP не поддерживает CPT в базовой версии, для того чтоб работать с CPT необходимо купить расширение у разработчика за $20 для одного сайта. Поэтому если вы делаете для кого-то можете предложить купить, а если для себя, то стоит обратить внимание на другие плагины.

Для себя сейчас подобрал плагин **Templatic Google AMP**, у него CPT работают. Когда будет больше информации - постараюсь поделиться.

**Better AMP - WordPress Complete AMP** тоже работают CPT, но мне он не понравился из-за того, что /amp/ идет не в конце ссылки, как у Templatic, а после домена.

- **Templatic Google AMP** пример URL: http://domain/category/post/amp/
- **Better AMP - WordPress Complete AMP** пример URL: http://domain/amp/category/post/